# Airflow “This DAG isnt available in the webserver DagBag object ”

Tags: airflow

I am currently setup airflow scheduler in Linux server A and airflow web server in Linux server B. Both server has no Internet access. I have start the initDB in server A and keep all the dags in server A.

However, when i refresh the webserver UI, it keep having error message:-

```
This DAG isn't available in the webserver DagBag object
```

How do i configure the dag folder for web server (server B) to read the dag from scheduler (server A)?

I am using bashoperator. Is that Celery Operator is a must?

Thanks in advance

Comment: My set up slightly different. Both scheduler and webserver are in different server.

Comment: How exactly does that make product behaviour Different ?

Comment: Product behavior should be same as I thought. But webserver need to read the dags which stored in proxy (different server) and I having problems on this. How can I share the dags without copying over?

Comment: Possible Duplicate of - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47834925/airflow-scheduler-not-picking-up-dag-runs

Comment: Interesting i ran into this when working in virtual environments and not having all packages installed globally when thinking I had them all working virtually - suggesting a setup issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The scheduler has found your `dags_folder`, and its processes, and is scheduling them accordingly. The webserver however can "see" these processes solely by their existence in the database but can't find them in *its* `dags_folder` path.

You need to ensure that the `dags_folder` for both servers contain the same files, and that both are kept in sync with one another. This is out of scope for Airflow and it won't handle this on your behalf.

Comment: Do you mean that I need to copy the dags from Linux A (Scheduler) to Linux B (web server)? Any easy way? Like to map drive and so on?

Comment: Essentially, yes. How you accomplish that is up to you.

Comment: Thanks. I still figure out how to map the drive